# How to link curl with net-snmp

Tags: curl, makefile, snmp, net-snmp

I am programming an application to be monitored with (net)snmp.

So when I run `snmpget` it will trigger a request for my program in C to get the data. The only problem is my program uses libcurl.

The function `getSettings` below uses libcurl:

```
HttpData* s = getSettings("max_ul_rate");
snmp_set_var_typed_value(requests->requestvb, ASN_OCTET_STR, (u_char *) &s->ptr, s->len+1);
```

When a I run netsnmp make it gives me an error that it doesn't find CURL. How can I add LIBCURL to NET-SNMP's Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

I found a person with a similar problem on StackOverFlow. Creating a makefile for a standalone piece of code using libcurl, should be the same process, so you could also google that.

[Linking cURL in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601041/linking-curl-in-makefile)

Comment: The link suggest compiling with C++ and I wanna do it with C.I tried putting
curlinstall: $(CURL_SOURCES) $(CURL_H) \
        $(CC) -o $(CURL_OUT) -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Werror -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl $(CURL_SOURCES)

It didnt work

Comment: Try this - it explains how to get the flags you need for gcc (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html). Also here are examples, which contain sample compilation flags (in the source) and parameters which you can make part of your Makefile.